# Typescript - Modify variables of an object through a callback function

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, variables, callback

I have a class that we'll call A with the following code

```
export class A{

  counter: number;

  constructor(public servicios: ServiciosProvider) {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.servicios.exeCallback(this.functionTocall)
   }

   functionToCall(): void {
     this.counter += 1;
   }
}
```

And then I have the following class B whith a callback function:

```
export class B{

      constructor() {
       }

       exeCallback(callback: Function): void {
       callback();
       }
}
```

When I try to execute this code I get an error saying that the variable counter is undefined.

Could someone lead me on how to increase that counter on the object that I used to call the `exeCallback`?

Thanks.

Comment: Same idea, you need to use `bind`, object methods don't carry their `this` around with them unless explicitly told to do so

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir i am not being able to do it with that, how would you call the "exeCallback" with the bind?

Comment: `this.servicios.exeCallback(this.functionTocall.bind(this))`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you very much it worked perfectly. You're great!

Comment: You can add an upvote to the duplicate :)

Comment: done =)  @TitianCernicova-Dragomir